# data not transfering from streams in java chatting app

Tags: java, io, stream

I am making chatting app in java and whole code is ok but the data isnot transferring from one client to server

when i click on login button the name it enters does not goes to server and neither the messages

plz suggest some method

chatting client.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Date;

public class ChattingClient extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JTextArea chat;
    JTextField msg;
    JButton send, exit, log, onlineuser;
    boolean logflag=false, onlineflag=false;
    OnlinePanel panel;
    static public String name;
    ServerSocket ss;
    Socket s;
    OutputStreamWriter out;
    BufferedReader br;
    JFrame frame;

    public ChattingClient()
    {
        init();
    }

    public void init()
    {
        setLayout(null);

        setSize(555,400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        chat=new JTextArea();
        chat.setBounds(5,5,530,240);
        chat.setEditable(false);

        msg=new JTextField();
        msg.setBounds(5,260,400,30);

        send=new JButton("Send");
        send.setBounds(405,260,70,30);
        send.addActionListener(this);

        onlineuser=new JButton(">>");
        onlineuser.setBounds(480,260,50,30);
        onlineuser.addActionListener(this);

        log=new JButton("Login");
        log.setBounds(150,310,95,30);
        log.addActionListener(this);

        exit=new JButton("Exit");
        exit.setBounds(280,310,95,30);
        exit.addActionListener(this);


        add(chat);
        add(msg);
        add(send);
        add(exit);
        add(onlineuser);
        add(log);
        setVisible(true);

        try 
        {
            s=new Socket("localhost",786);
            out=new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(true)
        {
                try
                {
                    br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    String value=br.readLine();
                    if (value.startsWith("came "))
                    {
                        OnlinePanel.list.add(br.readLine());
                    }
                    else if (value.startsWith("gone "))
                    {
                        OnlinePanel.list.remove(br.readLine());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(br.readLine()!=null)
                        {
                            chat.append(br.readLine());
                        }
                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        ChattingClient s=new ChattingClient();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource()==exit)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else if (e.getSource()==log)
        {
            if (logflag==true) 
            {
                log.setText("Login");
                logflag=false;
                try
                {
                    out.write("$#$#123456789$#$#logoutname "+name);
                    out.write("$#$#123456789$#$#logoutaddress "+s.getInetAddress());
                    System.out.println("logout "+name+" "+s.getInetAddress());
                } 
                catch (IOException e1) 
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                name=null;

            }
            else
            {
                name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter Name", "Name", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                if (name!=null)
                {
                    log.setText("Logout");
                    logflag=true;

                    try
                    {
                        out.write("$#$#987654321$#$#loginname "+name);
                        out.write("$#$#987654321$#$#loginaddress "+s.getInetAddress());
                        System.out.println("login "+name+" "+s.getInetAddress());
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e1) 
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        else if(e.getSource()==send)
        {
            if(name!=null)
            {
                try 
                {
                    out.write(name+": "+msg.getText());
                    System.out.println("msg: "+name+" "+msg.getText());
                } 
                catch (IOException e1) 
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                msg.setText(null);
            }
            else
            {`enter code here`
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Login First", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

chattingserver.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ChattingServer 
{
    public ChattingServer() 
    {

        Thread thread=new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                super.run();
                try 
                {
                    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(786);
                    Socket s=ss.accept();
                    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter (s.getOutputStream());

                    String input=null;
                    String login = null;
                    String logout = null;
                    String loginip=null;
                    String logoutip=null;
                    String msg = null;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        input=reader.readLine();

                        if(input.startsWith("$#$#123456789$#$#loginname "))
                        {
                            login="came "+input.substring(28);
                            System.out.println("login msg come "+login);
                        }
                        else if(input.startsWith("$#$#987654321$#$#logoutname "))
                        {
                            logout="gone "+input.substring(28);
                            System.out.println("logout msg come "+logout);
                        }
                        else if(input.startsWith("$#$#123456789$#$#loginaddress "))
                        {
                            loginip=input.substring(24);
                            System.out.println("loginip msg come "+loginip);
                        }
                        else if(input.startsWith("$#$#987654321$#$#logoutaddress "))
                        {
                            logoutip=input.substring(24);
                            System.out.println("logoutip msg come "+logoutip);
                        }
                        else if(input.startsWith("name: "))
                        {
                            msg=input.substring(7);
                            System.out.println("msg msg come "+msg);
                        }


                        if(login!=null)
                        {
                            out.write("\t\t\t"+login+"\t\t\t");
                            System.out.println("login msg goes "+login);
                            login=null;
                        }

                        if(logout!=null)
                        {
                            out.write("\t\t\t"+logout+"\t\t\t");
                            System.out.println("logout msg goes "+logout);
                            logout=null;
                        }

                        if(msg!=null)
                        {
                            out.write(msg);
                            System.out.println("msg msg goes "+msg);
                            msg=null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new ChattingServer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is waiting for a complete line (a bunch of characters followed by a `\n`), but you never send a `\n`, so the server keeps waiting for it. `write` does *not* automatically add one; you need to add it yourself:

```
out.write("$#$#987654321$#$#loginname "+name + "\n");
out.write("$#$#987654321$#$#loginaddress "+s.getInetAddress() + "\n");
```

Same for:

```
out.write(name+": "+msg.getText()+"\n");
```